# How can I get a record which has two corresponding columns which are multiple in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, I have two tables:

```
ID | Name
------------
1  | test 1 
2  | test 2 

ID2| ID | Age
--------------
1  | 1  | 18
2  | 1  | 18
3  | 1  | 19
4  | 2  | 18
5  | 2  | 19
```

I want to have all records that have columns which are multiple in name with age but I don't know how to do that.

I want an output like this:

```
Name     | Age
--------------------
test 1   | 18
test 1   | 18
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: a join will work just fine

Comment: I edited my question to describe my problem more exactly

Comment: why do you want to print same row twice?

Comment: *multiple in name* what does this mean?

Comment: In my program there are some more columns which are different in both rows

Comment: the name appears multiply in a table (sorry I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: do both tables have more columns than you showed here?

Comment: yes, this example should be simple for you so you have a better overview

Comment: actually, it won't make it simple. in fact, it'll make us providing wrong solutions. You should mention this in your question in order to get correct result.

Comment: Small remark. If those names are persons, then more often one would store the birthday of the persons.  Then calculate the age from that date in the queries.  Much easier than having to correct Age values in the tables.

Comment: I test the answers below and if this isn't working I'll update my question

Comment: The age is an example. In my program I use datetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query:

```
Select t1.*, t2.* 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on  t1.id = t2.id
join (select id, age
      from table2
      group by id, age
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t3
on t1.id = t2.id and t2.id = t3.id and t2.age = t3.age
```

Comment: i've updated the query based on your comments. Please try updated query

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH IT WORKS

Comment: glad to help. Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.age = t.age and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

With an index on `(name, age, id)`, this should be the fastest approach.

Comment: The problem is what is if I have two tables: I mean in one table is ID and Name and in the other table is an AGE_ID, the ID of the other table (foreign key) and the age

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `IN` on tupples.

And a GROUP BY can be combined with a HAVING to only get those that have duplicate  (name, age).

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Age
FROM YourTable2 t2
LEFT JOIN YourTable1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (t2.ID, t2.Age) IN (
      SELECT ID, Age
      FROM YourTable2
      GROUP BY ID, Age
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  );
```